# How to prevent vue-cli project from automatically adding semi-colons

Tags: vue-cli, vue-cli-3, automatic-semicolon-insertion

I just created a new vue-cli project using `vue create my-project-name` and although i manually didn't install eslint still when i save a javascript file without semi-colons they automatically get added, how do i prevent this? I think it might be babel causing this.

Comment: You should be able to configure that in the extension settings (assuming you're using VS Code). It could be a number of things; Prettier, Vuetify, or ESLint itself, depending on what you have installed.

Comment: @LenJoseph i'm afraid i'm not using VS Code i'm using neovim

Comment: It may be a good idea to modify your question to include that environment so people who work with it will find your inquiry.